# How to fetch data from database based on current user login in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to fetch data from database based on current user login? As example, when user login and open your page, it only display his/her data only.

Comment: Use a "where" clause => select * from table where username = '$username'

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's solution. (it's working code from my similar project).

Controller:

```
public function actionVacancyList()
{

    if ( !Yii::$app->user->isGuest )
    {
        $user_vacancies = Vacancies::getVacanciesByUser(Yii::$app->user->id);

        return $this->render('vacancy-list', [
            'user_vacancies' => $user_vacancies,
        ]);
    }
    return $this->redirect(['/site/login']);

}
```

Model:

```
static public function getVacanciesByUser($user_id)
{
    return Vacancies::find()
        ->where(['user_id' => $user_id])
        ->orderBy('id DESC')
        ->limit(100)
        ->all();
}
```

Comment: In case of topic starter the best practice is to use Active Record to get results in objects for comfortable rendering in views. 

Thus:

1. You check user is guest or not in Controller. 
2. If not, get the user id with Yii::$app->user->id and pass to model method.
3. Get from database results with AR (ActiveRecord) with clause for logging in specific user and pass to view.
4. Render view.

Answer (score 0):

you should use WHERE CLAUSE

Example:

```
$sql = "Select * from datatable Where username = username";
```

Comment: actually this query i know that but actually i am making a employee management system so how can i show particular data of employee

Comment: in your query just use where clause. to fetch data on specific person or whatever it is,

Answer (score 0):

You can get authenticated user information with `Yii::$app->user->identity` and then get data you need from database.

Comment: actually this query i know that but actually i am making a employee management system so how can i show particular data of employee

Comment: check this out: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac) Its easy to implement and manage. assuming there other sections in your app that you would need to control access to different users.